# iTunes Match: Matched songs are now Uploaded and I can't download the 256kbps version of songs

Tags: itunes, icloud, itunes-match, itunes-store

I subscribed to iTunes Match yesterday and let matching process run overnight. This morning, most of my tunes were matched.  I wanted to upgrade my matched 128kbps bitrate tracks for iTunes Store 256kbps bitrate tracks.

I followed the instructions [here](http://howto.cnet.com/8301-11310_39-57326759-285/how-to-use-itunes-match-to-upgrade-audio-quality/), which created a Smart Playlist of all the 128kbps tracks that were matched.  I saw all the tunes that I wanted to upgrade in that playlist. So I followed the instructions to delete one song.  After I deleted the song from the playlist, I was able to download a 256kbps version from the Store.  Seeing that the process worked, I decided to repeat that process for all songs in the playlist. I selected all the songs from the playlist and deleted.  All the tunes listed in the smart playlist disappeared from the playlist.  But there were still in my Music library.  Now the iCloud Status of each of the songs that I wanted to upgrade has changed from Matched to Uploaded.  If I delete a 128kbps song and try to download it, I still get the 128kbps version of that song.  An example is The Beatles "Here Comes the Sun".  This song is available in the ITunes Store and I'm 100% certain its status was Matched before I deleted it from the playlist but now its status is uploaded and I can't get the 256kbps version.

I quit iTunes (10.6.1 and I'm on OSX 10.7.4) and tried "Update iTunes Match" several times but status of all those songs in playlist is still Uploaded. So how do I fix this so that I can download 256kbps versions of my formerly Matched 128kbps songs?